# My ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS always requires manual fsck(Duel boot with Windows)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount, fsck

Recently I removed my swap partition totally and combined it with root partition due to storage requirements.Soon after that my system shows the message UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY;RUN fsck MANUALLY.I know there's many questions and answers related to it but `none solves my issue permanently`.I have to keep on repeating fsck manually most of the time I boot in.I at times read linux storage from windows using `linux reader from DiskInternals Research`.

Comment: Any Windows app/driver that tries to r/w to Linux ext2/3/4 partitions ends up corrupting them. Don't do that. fsck it once more, and be happy.

Comment: Thanks..Hope it doesn't throw this error ever again.